# Do I need to add Babel and React in both NPM package.json and in the main index.html or only in one place is enough?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Where is the place to put Babel and React libraries (or references to it) when using Node.js with React and JSX (Babel is needed for JSX):

1. Only in the project package.json.
2. Only in the main index.html file.
3. In both.
   And if I use package.json, do I need to put references in the index.html () to the node_modules/ and  modules?
   Thank you,

Comment: The entries in the package.json are only relevant for your package manager, and spares you the hassle to install and manage third party packages manually. The remainder of the question depends on your build process.  Do you use a bundler like webpack?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I currently do not use any bundler, since I want to understand how a Web site is built from the scratch (pure HTML/CSS) and then adding JavaScript, packages and libraries. Currently I use script tag at the end of the index.html to refer to Babel and to React library, however as far as I can understand in my case no local modules will be used. Do bundlers add the necessary script line automatically to the index.html?

Comment: No, in a nutshell, bundlers combine multiple javascript files into one single file, so you don't need to have multiple <script> tags in you html and probable the most important aspect is that the bundler will ensure to add the files in the correct order if some of the code relies on other code